# The best way to compare two dates without a respect to their timezone difference?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

I have two dates: one in 'UTC' and the other 'America/Los_Angeles'. How can I compare these two ignoring their timezone difference i.e. I want to check if their year, month, day, hour, ... are equal to each other?

```
  local_date_string = '2014-09-19T09:00:00'
  local_date = local_date_string.to_datetime

  time_zone_name = 'America/Los_Angeles'

  timezone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone[time_zone_name]

  date_with_zone = ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone.new(nil, timezone, local_date)

  date_utc = date_with_zone.utc

  local_date_with_zone_from_utc = date_utc.in_time_zone(timezone)

  puts local_date.hour => 9
  puts local_date_with_zone_from_utc.hour => 9

  how to compare_ignoring_tz_diff(local_date, local_date_with_zone_from_utc) ?
```

Comment: I typically store only UTC and convert to timezone-specific datetimes when outputting to somewhere that requires it, it ensures that anything centrally computed will work in a robust manner (and can also help performance at a low level), but I'm not sure if this method is applicable to what you are working on. Either way you should get some good help and there are a lot of resources about this problem around the web and here on SO.

Comment: What @Jacob describes is the Rails default, ie all times are stored in UTC in the database, and just converted to the local timezone for display purposes.  I'm not sure what you want.  If a London user creates a record at 9pm london time, and a New York user creates a record at 9pm New York time (on the same day), do you want your test to return that these times are equal?

Comment: Max, yes! For now I am going to just use such comparison method inside my unit tests! I do understand your point about auto-conversion to localtime when a date is displayed in user's localtime.

Comment: The what I'm asking: is there a way to compare these two dates without direct comparison of .hour==.hour, .day==.day etc...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for the `time` method from `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`. This returns a `Time` object with a time zone of +0000 but with all the components (hour, minute, day) etc. unchanged.

If you have two time with zones, then call this on both and compare the result ie

```
def compare_without_tz(first, second)
  first.time == second.time
end
```

This assumes both arguments are `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` - if you want to also be able to pass normal instances of `Time`, `DateTime` then you'll need to check whether their type first